# Limit of differences of products

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Is the following true:

If $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=A$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}c_k=C$ then
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\Big(a_kb_k-c_kd_k\Big)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\Big(Ab_k-Cd_k\Big).$$

This equality could be either finite or infinite, and nothing is assumed about either $b_k$ or $d_k$.

I suspect it's not true when the convergence of $a_k$ and $c_k$ is too slow but I can't put together a proof.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $a_k=\frac1k$, $b_k=k$, $c_k=d_k=0$.

Comment: Damn! Thanks though.

Comment: How about if $A$ and $C$ are both nonzero and $b_k$ and $d_k$ both diverge to infinity?